# Can a solvable trig equation become unsolvable if I rewrite it in terms of only $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I found this trigonometric equation which could easily be solved with a quadratic method:

> $$\tan^{4}(x) -3\tan^{2}+2=0$$

But I decided to rewrite it in sin(x) and cos(x), just to see if that approach would work:

> $$\frac{\sin^{4}(x)}{\cos^{4}(x)}- 3\frac{ \sin^{2}(x) }{ \cos^{2}(x)}+2=0$$

after multiplying everything out, and "simplifying" I solved it, but it got me thinking.

Is it possible that a trigonometric equation expressed in terms of the **standard and reciprocal** trigonometric functions would become symbolically unsolvable whence rewritten as an equation in terms of *only* $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$?

And by Solvable I mean:

> That it is possible to manipulate the equation such that I end up with $\sin(x) = k_{0}$ or $\cos(x)=k_{1}$ where both ks are numbers

Comment: What does "symbolically unsolvable" mean?  It's certainly the case that rewriting a trigonometric equation using various trig identities can "disguise" a problem, masking a straight forward solution.

Comment: To answer this question you must provide  precise definitions for "solvable" and "symbolically unsolvable".

Comment: If you define $\sin x=t$, then the five other trigonometric ratios follow ($\cos x=\sqrt{1-t^2}, \tan x=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$, and so on...)

Answer (score 2):

> *That it is possible to manipulate the equation such that I end up with $\sin(x) = k_0 \text{ or } \cos(x) = k_1$ where both $k_0, k_1$ are numbers*

Yes, it is indeed possible. However, it is nowhere as efficient of a method compared to quadratic substitution.

Nonetheless, to be amused and have some fun:

> Reduce the powers: $\tan^2{x} = \dfrac{1 - \cos{2x}}{1 + \cos{2x}}$

Hence,

$$\tan^4{x} - 3\tan^2{x} + 2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left(\dfrac{1 - \cos{2x}}{1 + \cos{2x}}\right)^2 - 3\left(\dfrac{1 - \cos{2x}}{1 + \cos{2x}}\right) + 2 = 0 \\
\to \dfrac{1 - 2\cos{2x} + \cos^2{2x}}{(1 + \cos{2x})^2} - 3\left(\dfrac{1 - \cos^2{2x}}{(1 + \cos{2x})^2}\right) + 2 = 0 \\
\to \dfrac{1 - 2\cos{2x} + \cos^2{2x} - 3\sin^2{2x}}{(1 + \cos{2x})^2} + \dfrac{2(1 + \cos{2x})^2}{(1 + \cos{2x})^2} = 0 \\
\to \dfrac{1 - 2\cos{2x} + \cos^2{2x} - 3\sin^2{2x} + 2 + 4\cos{2x} + 2\cos^2{2x}}{(1 + \cos{2x})^2} = 0 \\ 
\to \dfrac{3 + 2\cos{2x} + 3\cos^2{2x} - 3(1 - \sin^2{2x})}{(1 + \cos{2x})^2} = 0 \\
\to \dfrac{2(3\cos^2{2x} + \cos{2x})}{(1 + \cos{2x})^2} = 0 \\ \quad \\
\therefore \cos{2x} \cdot \big( 3\cos{2x} + 1 \big) = 0$$

Ideally, the equation is simplified enough to evaluate $x$, but we continue a bit further to suit the answer you need:

> Using, $\cos{2x} = 1 - 2\sin^2{x} = 2\cos^2{x} - 1$

$$\cos{2x} \cdot \big( 3\cos{2x} + 1 \big) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \big( 2\cos^2{x} - 1 \big) \cdot \big( 4 - 6\sin^2{x} \big) = 0 \\ \quad \\
\therefore \sin{x} = \pm\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}, \space \cos{x} = \pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \text{ and hence, } \\ k_0 = \pm\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}, \space k_1 = \pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks. So rewriting a trig equation in terms of sin and cos and then restricting yourself only to the identities that exclusively deal with sin and cos doesn’t make a previously solvable equation ever become unsolvable?

Comment: @Maalik Yes. However, not every identity manipulation works. In this particular case, we reduced the quartic tangent to a quadratic cosine so we could deal with smaller and easier polynomials. However, a substitution like $\tan^2{x} + 1 = \sec^2{x}$ would not be useful and complicate the quartic further. If your ever come across a polynomial of trig functions, you best method is to reduce the powers, unless the most useful variable substitution works. Ie. as you pointed out, it could be easily solved by letting $t = \tan^2{x}$